# SSH localhost always ask for password. But the password is not the ROOT password

Tags: linux, ssh

I am driving crazy now.
I want to ssh localhost in my laptop. So i want to ssh localhost without password.
So I run the following commands in my mac.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

chmod og-wx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

chmod 755 ~/.ssh
```

But it still needs password, So i enter the my root password but it is not right.
Here is the dubug information.
[debug information1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K112H.jpg)
[debug information2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdc2t.jpg)
Please someone helps me! I am going to be CRAZY! Appreciate!

Comment: Please generate a new key that doesn't need a password

Comment: That's strange. Why do you want to ssh to localhost? It is your computer and you are already on it. If your localhost is remote, you should use a remote ip.

Comment: I want to start hadoop  in standalone mode in my mac So I want to ssh localhost in my mac. And I have tried many times to generate a new key but it still needs password.